# How to introduce a menu active effect in wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress

I have a challenge and will appreciate any assistance please.
I'm working with the wordpress sydney theme. I want to introduce an active(or current - if you like) effect to change the color of the menu of the current page.I have created a child theme, and have the necessary files in that folder but can't figure out where to effect the modification.I tried creating a new header file in the child theme to structure this but my website got crashed and i had to undo that. Kindly assist..

Comment: wp_nav_menu automatically puts the active class on an active menu item. You can then style it with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Using wp_get_nav_menu_items() you can apply active menu item effect.

```
<?php
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu_name');
  $id   = get_the_ID(); 
  foreach($menu as $menuitem)
  {
     if($id == $menuitem->object_id)
     {
        echo '<li class = "nav-active">';  //apply active class here
        echo '<a href ="'.$menuitem->url.'">'.$menuitem->title.'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
     }
    else
    {
        echo '<li>';
        echo '<a href ="'.$menuitem->url.'">'.$menuitem->title.'</a>';
        echo '</li>';
    }
 }
?>
```